# if-else condition with for loop throws up missing value error although no missing values in variables

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to write a loop to create a variable to later use group_by on  for further calculation, which indicates whether a particular type (group variable) happened between two dates (date variable). The factor I want to create is called leaderFactor.

The code throws up an error: "Error in if (test1$party[i] == "PSOE" & test1$elecTypeDate[i] > as_date("1977-01-01") &  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed", but there are no missing values contained in the two relevant variables. Please help! Thank you!

(Sidenote: This is an example of a more complex scenario with more than two types of events, so I will use several else if statements between the if and the else in the code below.)

Data:

```
test1<- structure(list(party = c("PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", "PP", 
"PP", "PP", "PP", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", 
"PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE", "PSOE"), elecTypeDate = structure(c(3346, 
3346, 3346, 3712, 4291, 4503, 4656, 4656, 4656, 4656, 4656, 4656, 
4656, 4656, 4656, 4656, 4656, 4656, 4656, 4868, 4868, 4868, 4868, 
4868, 4868, 4868, 4868, 4868, 4868, 4991, 4991, 4991, 5144, 5204, 
5783, 5995, 6148, 6209, 6360, 6360, 6360, 6360, 6360, 6360, 6360, 
6360, 6360, 6360, 6360, 6360, 6360, 6695, 6940, 7274, 7456, 7578, 
7790, 7790, 7790, 7790, 7790, 7790, 7790, 7790, 7790, 7790, 7790, 
7790, 7821, 8095, 8674, 8766, 8917, 9039, 9251, 9251, 9251, 9251, 
9251, 9251, 9251, 9251, 9251, 9282, 9282, 9282, 9435, 9556, 10135, 
10500, 10592, 10743, 10743, 10743, 10743, 10743, 10743, 10743, 
10743, 10743, 10743, 10743, 10835, 10865, 11017, 11443, 11596, 
12173, 12173, 12173, 12173, 12173, 12173, 12173, 12173, 12173, 
12204, 12204, 12296, 12326, 12357, 12418, 12478, 12874, 12935, 
13453, 13634, 13634, 13634, 13634, 13634, 13634, 13634, 13634, 
13634, 13634, 13665, 13695, 13939, 14245, 14245, 14304, 14304, 
14914, 15095, 15095, 15095, 15095, 15095, 15095, 15095, 15095, 
15095, 15095, 15095, 15095, 15126, 15400, 15400, 15614, 15614, 
15645, 16102, 16495, 16556, 16556, 16556, 16556, 16556, 16556, 
16556, 16556, 16556, 16556, 16556, 16556, 16587, 16679, 17045, 
17045, 17501, 17622, 17928, 17987, 18017, 18017, 18017, 18017, 
18017, 18017, 18017, 18017, 18017, 18017, 18017, 18017, 3346, 
3346, 3346, 3346, 3377, 3712, 3712, 4291, 4503, 4656, 4656, 4656, 
4656, 4656, 4656, 4656, 4656, 4656, 4656, 4656, 4656, 4656, 4868, 
4868, 4868, 4868, 4868, 4868, 4868, 4868, 4868, 4868, 4991, 4991, 
4991, 5144, 5204, 5783, 5995, 6148, 6209, 6360, 6360, 6360, 6360, 
6360, 6360, 6360, 6360, 6360, 6360, 6360, 6360, 6360, 6695, 6940, 
7274, 7456, 7578, 7790, 7790, 7790, 7790, 7790, 7790, 7790, 7790, 
7790, 7790, 7790, 7790, 7821, 8095, 8674, 8766, 8917, 9039, 9251, 
9251, 9251, 9251, 9251, 9251, 9251, 9251, 9251, 9251, 9282, 9282, 
9282, 9435, 9556, 10135, 10500, 10592, 10743, 10743, 10743, 10743, 
10743, 10743, 10743, 10743, 10743, 10743, 10743, 10743, 10835, 
10865, 11017, 11443, 11596, 12173, 12173, 12173, 12173, 12173, 
12173, 12173, 12173, 12173, 12173, 12204, 12204, 12296, 12326, 
12357, 12418, 12478, 12874, 12935, 13453, 13634, 13634, 13634, 
13634, 13634, 13634, 13634, 13634, 13634, 13634, 13634, 13665, 
13695, 13939, 14245, 14304, 14304, 14914, 15095, 15095, 15095, 
15095, 15095, 15095, 15095, 15095, 15095, 15095, 15095, 15095, 
15126, 15400, 15400, 15614, 15614, 15645, 16102, 16495, 16556, 
16556, 16556, 16556, 16556, 16556, 16556, 16556, 16556, 16556, 
16556, 16556, 16587, 16679, 17045, 17045, 17501, 17622, 17928, 
17987, 18017, 18017, 18017, 18017, 18017, 18017, 18017, 18017, 
18017, 18017, 18017, 18017), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-398L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Code:

```
test1$leaderFactor <- "none"
for(i in test1$leaderFactor){
  if(test1$party[i]=="PSOE" & 
     test1$elecTypeDate[i] > as_date("1977-01-01") & 
                               test1$elecTypeDate[i] < as_date("1997-06-30")){
    test1$leaderFactor[i] = "Gonzales"
   } else {
    test1$leaderFactor[i] = "Rest"}}
sum(is.na(test1$elecTypeDate))
sum(is.na(test1$party))
```

Comment: As an aside, you don’t need to convert the variable to a factor to use `group_by`.

Comment: Try with `as.Date`, worked for me.

Comment: `df  <-  data.frame(group=rep(c(1,2),each=3), date=rep(c("2001-06-01", "2002-10-01", "2003-06-01"),2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE);
df$futureFactor <- ifelse(df$group==1 & df$date > "2001-01-01" & df$date < "2002-12-31", "a", "b")`

Comment: @jay.sf Using `as.Date` instead of `as_date` that gives the exact same error.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Using `R 4.0.0`, just base packages loaded, no errors, sorry.

Comment: @jay.sf Ah right, because R 4.0 has `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`.

Answer (score 2):

First off, why use a loop? You can write the same without a loop:

```
df <- data.frame(
    group = rep(c(1, 2), each = 3),
    date = as_date(rep(c("2001-06-01", "2002-10-01", "2003-06-01"), 2))
)

df$futureFactor <- ifelse(
    df$group == 1
    & df$date > as_date("2001-01-01")
    & df$date < as_date("2002-12-31"),
    "a", "b"
)
```

The resulting code is shorter, more R-like and runs more efficiently.

If using `if` instead of `ifelse`, always use `&&` (and `||`) instead of `&` (and `|`): the latter are vectorised, but `if` only accepts a *single value*, and fails if you provide more than one, so vectorisation plain doesn’t make sense.

Now, why does your code fail? Because you’re trying to compare dates and factors, and R gives you a helpful warning (which should really be an error):

> Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", ">.Date") for ">"

You need to ensure that your data has the right type, by defining `df$date` using `as_date`, as done in my code above.

Comment: "Sidenote: This is an example of a more complex scenario with more than two types of events, so I will use several else if statements between the if and the else in the code below."

Comment: I realized the factor-date comparison problem. Your answer refers to an example I made to illustrate the problem, which is not that one of the vars was not a date. I have now just put the code directly from the script (though still excluding the else if in-betweeners).

Comment: @Spaniel For more than two cases you can use `case_when` from ‘dplyr’ instead of `ifelse`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use seq_along() around around test1$leaderFactor